# How do I find a specific cell within a cell array?

Tags: matlab, indexing, cell-array

Let's say I have a cell array containing 1x2 cells. eg. `deck = {{4,'c'},{6,'s'}...{13,'c'}...{6,'d'}}`

How can I find the index of a specific cell? E.g I want to find the index of the cell with the values `{13,'c'}`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method I can suggest is to operate on each column separately.  We could use logical operators on each column to search for cards in your cell array that contain a specific number in the first column, followed by a specific suit in the second column.  To denote a match, we would check to see where these two outputs intersect.  We can do this by combining both outputs with a logical `AND` when we're done:

```
deck = {{4,'c'},{6,'s'},{13,'c'},{6,'d'}};
target_card = {13, 'c'};

deck_unroll = vertcat(deck{:});    
a1 = cat(1, deck_unroll{:,1}) == target_card{1};
a2 = cat(1, deck_unroll{:,2}) == target_card{2};
found = a1 & a2  

found =

     0
     0
     1
     0
```

Because `deck` is a nested cell array, I unrolled it so that it becomes a 2D cell array where each row denotes one card.  This is stored in `deck_unroll`.  Once I do this, I further unroll the cells so that the first column gets placed into a numeric array and we search for a particular number (13 in your example) and the second column gets placed into a string array where we search for a particular character (`'c'` in your example).  This is done with the help of [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) to extract each element from a particular column and we construct an array out of these elements.

Answer (score 4):

Try [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) with [`isequal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html):

```
>> deck = {{4,'c'},{6,'s'},{13,'c'},{6,'d'}};
>> targetCell = {13,'c'};
>> found = cellfun(@(c) isequal(c,targetCell),deck)
found =
     0     0     1     0
```

`cellfun` let's you check anyway you want (not just `isequal`).  For example, if you want to check based on the string element in each cell:

```
>> targetLetter = 'c';
>> found = cellfun(@(c) strcmp(c{2},targetLetter),deck)
found =
     1     0     1     0
```

Comment: Nice job with `isequal`!