# How to find the index of a cell (vector case) in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I just search the following related discussions:

1. [How do I find a specific cell within a cell array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746614/how-do-i-find-a-specific-cell-within-a-cell-array).

   2. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/84242-find-in-a-cell-array

However, they are not what I want exactly.

```
v = [1 0]; u = [0 1];
C = {v, u; u, u+u}
```

I create a cell C above with each element a row vector.

If I do

```
C{2,2}
```

it shows

```
ans =

 0     2
```

> Inversely, if I know [0 2], I want to find where it is, i.e., I want to get {2,2}, how could I do?

For the scalar case, the answer is shown in the second link; however, I cannot find the answer for the vector case so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27746705/11756186) you linked to you can do :

```
found = cellfun(@(c) isequal(c,[0 2]),c)
```

which outputs

```
found =

  2×2 logical array

   0   0
   0   1
```

lastly to get the coordinates you would use [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html?searchHighlight=find&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) :

```
[row,col] = find(found==1)
```

The output will be

```
row = 2
col = 2
```

Comment: Nice and clean! Thanks!